# Solving ODE's on Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, modeling

I'm having trouble solving a system of ODE's on mathematica. Any help would be appreciated

```
eq = Flatten@({0 == a'[t] == 
      k1*b[t] - 
       k2*a[t][0 == b'[t] == k3*a[t] - k1*b[t] - k4*{b[t]*c[t]}][
         0 == c'[t] == k5*a[t] - k6*c[t] - k4*{b[t]*c[t]}], 
     a[0] == 10, b[0] == 0, c[0] == 0}) /. {k1 -> 0.025, k2 -> 0.25, 
   k3 -> 1.0, k4 -> 7.5*10^-6, k5 -> 1000, k6 -> 1.99}
sol = NDSolve[eq, {a, b, c}, {t, 0, 200}],[{k1*b - k2*a == 0, k3*a - k1*b - k4*b*c == 0] 
   k5*a - k6*c - k4*b*c == 0} /. {k1 -> 0.025, k2 -> 0.25, k3 -> 1.0, 
   k4 -> 7.5*10^-6, k5 -> 1000, k6 -> 1.99}, {a, b, c}]
```

> {{a -> 0., b -> 0., c -> 0.}, {a -> 19.9149, b -> 199.149, c -> 10000.}}

```
Plot[Evaluate[a[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: You have syntax error. This `0 == a'[t] == k1*b[t] - k2*a[t]`   makes no sense.

Comment: how should I format it? because I need to set the time derivative to zero because its in steady state

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4):

If you replace `0==a'[t]==RHS` with just `a'[t]==RHS` and use `Thread` on those inner multiplications, then it gives answer

```
eq = Flatten@({a'[t] == k1*b[t] - k2*a[t],
     Thread[b'[t] == k3*a[t] - k1*b[t] - k4*{b[t]*c[t]}],
     Thread[c'[t] == k5*a[t] - k6*c[t] - k4*{b[t]*c[t]}], a[0] == 1, 
     b[0] == 0, c[0] == 0}) /. {k1 -> 0.025, k2 -> 0.25, k3 -> 1.0, 
   k4 -> 7.5*10^-6, k5 -> 1000, k6 -> 1.99}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol=NDSolve[eq, {a, b, c}, {t, 0, 200}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Plot[Evaluate[a[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Evaluate[{a[t], b[t], c[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 200},PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking for the steady state solutions, you do not need to solve the ODE. It's just algebra. Let `a`, `b`, and `c` be the steady state solutions, then they must fulfill:

```
Solve[{k1*b - k2*a == 0, k3*a - k1*b - k4*b*c == 0, 
   k5*a - k6*c - k4*b*c == 0} /. {k1 -> 0.025, k2 -> 0.25, k3 -> 1.0, 
   k4 -> 7.5*10^-6, k5 -> 1000, k6 -> 1.99}, {a, b, c}]

{{a -> 0., b -> 0., c -> 0.}, {a -> 19.9149, b -> 199.149, c -> 10000.}}
```

Apparently there are two steady state solutions.